# Batch convert docx files to pdf

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, pdf, conversion

I have many DOCX files (of Office 365) that I need to convert to PDF. I can open each one of them and export to PDF, but I am looking for a faster solution that can run in a batch file. 
One option that almost works is to use LibreOffice as explained [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/6571/whats-the-best-way-to-batch-convert-odf-to-pdf-on-windows/). It works for simple docx files, but for more complex files (e.g. with images and rtl text) it messes up the layout of the file. 
Is there a way to do the same with MS Word?

Comment: Try using Adobe Acrobat to convert multiple DOCX files to PDF. Quote "Open Adobe Acrobat and select “Create PDF” at the right-side toolbar. Choose “Multiple iles”>”Create Multiple PDF Files”. Then press “Next”.
Add Word files using the browse button and click on “OK”. Specify the output folder and click on “OK” to start the conversion."  See this article below: https://www.pdfconverters.net/how-to/batch-convert-word-documents-to-pdf/

Comment: You probably'll need something that is able to convert from the command line and than make a script that runs it on every file in a directory or maybe the command'll have to accept something link *.docx

Comment: @RicardoBohner exactly, this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have Microsoft Word installed, you can use the `docx2pdf` command line utility to batch convert docx to pdf on windows or macos. https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf

Install:

```
pip install docx2pdf
```

Run:

```
docx2pdf myfolder/
```

Disclaimer: I wrote this tool after struggling to find a cross-platform solution for batch converting docx to pdf with zero formatting issues.

Comment: Wow, that was tremendously useful, tnanks !

Comment: God I appreciate you @al JohriG. Thanks for sharing your nice tool!

Answer (score 7):

There is

this [Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16537996/2235831),

the freeware [File Converter](https://file-converter.org/index.html),

and this readonly modified version of the doc2pdf.vbs script from [winhelponline](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-batch-convert-word-documents-into-pdf-files/):

```
'Convert .doc or .docx to .pdf files via Send To menu
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For i= 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count -1
    docPath = WScript.Arguments(i)
    docPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(docPath)
    If LCase(Right(docPath, 4)) = ".doc" Or LCase(Right(docPath, 5)) = ".docx" Then
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    pdfPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(docPath) & "\" & _
      fso.GetBaseName(docpath) & ".pdf"
    objWord.Visible = False
    Set objDoc = objWord.documents.open(docPath,,True)
        objDoc.saveas pdfPath, 17
        objDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
        objWord.Quit   
    End If   
Next
```

You can also add it to your Windows SendTo folder:

1. Open File Explorer and browse the following SendTo folder:

   C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
2. Create a shortcut to the script *doc2pdf.vbs* in the SendTo folder.
3. Prefix the shortcut target with *wscript.exe* followed by a
   space.

   [image]
4. Name the shortcut accordingly — e.g., *Convert Word Docs to PDF
   batch convert word documents to pdf*
5. Open the folder that contains the Word documents that you want
   to convert to PDF.
6. Select the documents, right-click on the selection, and click *Send to*.
7. Click *Convert Word Docs to PDF* in the *Send to* menu.
   batch convert word documents to pdfThat’s it! Your PDF files are now
   ready!
   batch convert word documents to pdf